# Помогите разобраться с tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Пытаюсь запустить простой сервлет

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s = "<html>" +"<header><title>This is title</title></header>" + "<body>" + "Hello World" + "</body>" + "/html";
        resp.getWriter().write(s);
    }
}
```

, а вылетает такое окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Все переменные среды прописаны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде пишите - ("/hello"), а в браузере - "/helo"